# Match two dates and return true if match

Tags: javascript

```
function isInDate(MatchDate, entries) {
    for (c = 0; c < entries.length; c++) {
        var entry = entries[c];
        var DateFrom = new Date(entry.DateFrom);
        var DateTo = new Date(entry.DateTo);

        if (
            DateFrom.getMonth() <= MatchDate.getMonth() &&
            DateFrom.getDay() <= MatchDate.getDay() &&
            DateTo.getDay() >= MatchDate.getDay()
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I am passing in a "MatchDate" that I want to compare with every looped entries "DateFrom" and "DateTo", if the matchdate is in the timespan I want to return true, otherwise false.

It should also return true if its the same day as DateFrom & same day as DateTo... I can't get it to work whatever I try.. Could anyone please assist?

Comment: Style note: use lower camel case (`matchDate`, `dateFrom`, etc.) for variable names.

Comment: You should also declare variables in loops: `for (var c = 0; ...)`.

Comment: You want any of the dates  to match or return false when they don't?

Answer (score 3):

getDay returns the day of the week, not the day of the month.

You want to use [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

And you can simply just do

```
return MatchDate >= DateFrom && MatchDate <= DateTo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like:

```js
var pre = onload, isInDate; //for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
isInDate = function(MatchDate, entries){
  for(var c=0,l=entries.length; c<l; c++) {
    var entry = entries[c], DateFrom = new Date(entry.DateFrom), DateTo = new Date(entry.DateTo);
    var md = MatchDate.getTime();
    if(!(DateFrom.getTime() <= md && DateTo.getTime() >= md)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
}
```